# Creating a sample React app on Windows with npx

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I have Node.js installed on my Windows system so that npx and npm are globally available, and I use the following to create a sample app

```
npx create-react-app sampleapp
```

All the files are created, but when I try to start the app with

```
npm start
```

The browser that opens gives the message

```
No Server Root

This server is not based inside of a workspace, so the index does not direct to anything.
```

Is there something else I need to do on Windows to be able to start the app? Thanks.